# Acrobat X "moves" object on save from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-acrobat

Have an odd issue with Acrobat X, when selecting an object (`Tools > Edit Object`). I then right click and "Edit Object" which opens Illustrator CS5.1, make my necessary changes, which 9/10 is colour, MAKING SURE NOT TO MOVE ANY OF THE OBJECTS IN ILLUSTRATOR. I then click "Save" in Illustrator and my changes are saved back to the PDF.

When reverting to my PDF to view the changes, the object has shifted, a seemingly random amount, usually to the right and upwards, meaning the document looks odd. This is not behaviour experienced on Acrobat 9 of which we have a couple of users. However, other users of 10 are not seeing this either so it appears to be machine specific.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this, by luck or judgement, by re-installing Illustrator.

I don't know why this would fix it but I made sure I removed the preferences also for that application and all seems well upon re-install.

Hopefully this helps someone.